# Eeeeek! Chat is Dead!

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I got "unknown error" when posting a chat message, then tried to reload.

This is what I got:

[image: chat cause 404 error message]

Can you please bring the chat back?

This affects all chat domains for me:

- https://chat.stackoverflow.com
- https://chat.stackexchange.com
- https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com

Browser: Chrome 86 (latest version)
OS: Windows 10 Home
Location: Israel

Those are the response headers:

[image: response headers]

**Note**: it kept working on my phone for a while, now it doesn't work on the phone as well.

Comment: I too got that.

Comment: no-repro; chat.Meta and chat.SE work for me

Comment: @Mithical did you reload?

Comment: I did (on chat.SE, not chat.Meta).

Comment: @Shadow So, I got this feeling that chats have been closed (for sometime or whatever) for normal users. Because at the end of that message they write “if you’re administrator ... “

Comment: No repro for me

Comment: can repro... in singapore

Comment: No-repro (Netherlands)

Comment: Added more details, it's really weird.

Comment: @Knight no, that page is the generic "Page Not Found" for sites that don't exist, e.g. try going to https://foobarbaz.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The great israeli firewall has been completed perhaps?

Comment: @Luuklag - nope, because I can access chat with no issue

Comment: works for me (logged in and incognito)

Comment: @Luuklag and it also reach Singapore? Doubt it... ;)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek still doesn't work for you? Looks like something changed, since I can't chat even from phone now. :/

Comment: Works for me. @852172 That sounds like a great idea...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We think that there was a server that was misbehaving and have taken it off of the rotation. If you are still seeing issues with chat, please reply to this post.

<strike>**Update**: ok, we know that it is more than just the one server, working on it right now</strike>

**Another update**: looks like issue was with two servers, both should be behaving now. Please update if you can still repro.

---

> chat misbehaving
> reset troublesome servers
> the tavern awaits

Comment: Still happening, yes. (PC only, from phone it's fine.)

Comment: Go clear your cache and cookies ;) @ShadowWizardWearingMask

Comment: @Luuklag no luck, tried in a Guest mode (no cookies or cache there), and even tried `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: I saw your "And now?" message in Tavern, when trying to reply (from phone, where it still worked) poof.... same issue. *cry*

Comment: @rene finally someone believe me... ;)

Comment: What was the root cause of the misbehavior?

Comment: @RobertColumbia a specific service on a couple of boxes failed in a novel way that we had not previously been monitoring for. Root issue and monitoring addressed now.